# TS2351: Cannot use 'new' with an expression whose type lacks a call or construct signature. ANGULAR 8

Tags: angular, typescript, tslint

this.date = new Date();
TS LINTING ISSUE
Same code is having no issue in my colleague IDE
code is running without any error but out of nowhere it gives me this error.
NEED HELP

Answer (score 0):

I have faced similar issues in angular 8. First try recompiling and restarting your ide, could be a linter issue. Next, try setting the type of Date,

```
this.date: Date = new Date();
```

Comment: I have done with restarting. moreover i have used this statement 1000 of times in my project. it would be lengthy way. Plus no luck with this bro.

Comment: Can you share the angular, typescript and linter version you are using in the question?

Comment: "tslint": "~5.15.0",
    "typescript": "~3.5.3",

Comment: "tslint" has been deprecated, its been replaced with "typescript-eslint", and kindly update your npm packages.